# Button disable for specific time period in android studio

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to disable a button from 23:30 to 1:30 but i don't know how to do it.

With this below code i am able to disable button from 23 to 1 meaning button will be disabled from 23pm to 1 am but i want to disable button from 23:30 pm to 1:30 am.

````
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int hours = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getHours();
                if(hours == 23 || hours == 24||hours == 01){
                    //Disable


                }else{
                    //Enable

                    count10counter++;



                }   ```
````

Comment: Try using [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) with `getHour()` and `getMinutes()` to get the times you want.

Comment: @OrestesK disable .i am able to disable button with mentioned code but it works only hourly. Meaning button will be disabled on 23pm and i want to disable button from 23:30pm onwards

Comment: @AliasCartellano thank you for suggesting but i am from non coding background and I don't know how to do it

Comment: import java.time.LocalTime, create a `LocalTime` object using `LocalTime.now()` and then use `getHours()` and `getMinute()` to get the times you want.